# What's the correct way to join threads in Python multiprocessing and how these differ?

Tags: python, python-2.6

What's the correct way to join threads in multiprocessing, so the main program waits the completion of all threads before going ahead?

I have seen these 2 ways while researching, not sure how they differ especially the first one as the second one seems more common:

```
for i in range(100):
    j = Process(target=somefunc,args=(i,))
    j.start()

j.join()
```

And

```
jobs = []
for i in range(100):
    j = Process(target=somefunc,args=(i,))
    jobs.append(j)
    j.start()

for j in jobs:
    j.join()
```

I am on Python 2.6.6 due to limitations on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way is not correct, because it only waits for the last process that was created. It cannot wait for all other processes, because it didn't keep a reference to them before starting the next process.

The second way is correct, because it collects references to all started processes in a list and then waits for all of them.